# Footer will not go to bottom, showing over content

Tags: html, footer

https://jsfiddle.net/z4of8fvy/

I know my code is somewhat sloppy but I am still learning. I have run it through a validator to see if I had a missing  but I didn't find one. Any help would be appreciated.

If there are any other things that you guys can point out I would appreciate that as well. 
It keeps asking me for more details but I don't know what else I can say. I do know that at one point the footer was working with me keeping it position: sticky and bottom:0 but when I added more content that's when the problem appeared. That is when I tried to play with it a bit and probably ruined it even more.

```
<div id="topBar" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="logo" class="col-xs-6">
            <a id="homelink" href="https://smithstreetmediagroup.com"> 
            <h1>SMG <br> Studios </h1> 
            </a>
        </div>  
        <div id= "menu" class = "col-xs-6">
            <a class="topBar" href="mess.html"><h4>Me$$ aka M.T.M  </h4></a>
            <a class="topBar" href="services.html"><h4>Services </h4></a>
            <a class="topBar" href="campaigns.html"><h4>Campaigns </h4></a>
            <a class="topBar" href="jeybundy.html"><h4>Jey Bundy </h4></a>
            <a class="topBar" href="store.html"><h4>Store </h4></a>
            <a class="topBar" href="contact.html"><h4>Contact </h4></a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div  id="studioHome" class = "col-xs-4 mainOne">
            <h1> Studio Services </h1>
            <a href="services.html"> <h1 class="buttons"> Read More </h1> </a>
        </div>
        <div id="jbHome" class = "col-xs-4 mainOne">
            <h1> Jey Bundy </h1>
            <a href="services.html"> <h1 class="buttons"> Read More </h1> </a>
        </div>
        <div id="mtmHome" class = "col-xs-4 mainOne">
            <h1> Me$$ aka M.T.M </h1>
            <a href="services.html"> <h1 class="buttons"> Read More </h1> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 mainTwo">
            <h1>Our Mission</h1>
            <p>
                Smith media groups consist of a team of polite professionals that provide high quality and affordable service. We consider our customers family so we take pride in making our customers feel as comfortable and satisfied as possible. We offer a vast variety of services such as photoshoots, music videos, parties, wedding videos/photos, real estate photos, music production & duplication, ect. If you have any questions give us a call or use our contact form and we will give you a call. Our Vison, Your Success</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 mainTwo">

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5iSNm5c6dBs?rel=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12"> 
            <div id="slideshow">
                <div class="slideImg">
                    <img src="battleflyer.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slideImg">
                    <img src="bluesmoke.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slideImg">
                    <img src="streetview.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slideImg">
                    <img src="trackboard.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
</div>      
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row" id="bottomBar"> 
            <div class = "col-xs-4">

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/smithstreetmediagroup/"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"> Facebook</i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/smithmediagroup/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"> Instagram</i></a>



            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-4">

            </div>
            <div id="designer" class = "col-xs-4">
            <h6>Designed by Xavier Velez</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple these days. One line of code.

`min-height: 100vh;`

https://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/gXXMmr

Comment: This didn't make any change.

Comment: Use my code as a template. It's utilizing new CSS Grid and is what you will want to be using going forward. Notice how the view changes for phone vs tablet vs desktop (resize your browser windows width).